# C++ polygon rectangle and triangle inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to make a Polygon class and a Rectangle and Triangle that inherit the first. Polygon class has height and width variables that I want them to be be given values within the constructor. Then, Rectangle and Triangle have area calculation methods. Then, I use a main() to give some examples. I use:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Polygon {
    public:
        Polygon(int, int);
    protected:
        int height;
        int width;
};

class Rectangle: public Polygon {
    public:
        void calc_area();
};

class Triangle: public Polygon {
    public:
        void calc_area();
};

Polygon::Polygon(int a, int b) {
    height = a;
    width = b;
}

void Rectangle::calc_area() {
    cout << "Rectangle area: " << (height*width) << endl;
}

void Triangle::calc_area() {
    cout << "Triangle area: " << (height*width/2) << endl;
}

int main() {
    Rectangle s1(5, 2);
    Triangle s2(5, 2);
    s1.calc_area();
    s2.calc_area();
}
```

But while everything looks ok to my newbie eyes, I get a series of errors:

12 base Polygon' with only non-default constructor in class without a constructor `

36 no matching function for call to `Rectangle::Rectangle(int, int)

37 no matching function for call to `Triangle::Triangle(int, int)'

Can someone give me some tips? As seen, I am very new to C++...

Comment: Add a default constructor to Polygon class.

Comment: Indeed many of my problems were solved but still I get the last 38 error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call constructor to use `.`, such as:

```
Rectangle s1;
Triangle s2;
s1.Polygon(5, 2);
s2.Polygon(5, 2);
```

try this way:

```
Rectangle s1(5, 2);
Triangle  s2(5, 2);
```

and you should add constructor for `Rectangle` and `Triangle` respectively:

```
class Rectangle: public Polygon {
public:
    Rectangle(int height, int width):Polygon(height, width){}
    void calc_area();
};

class Triangle: public Polygon {
public:
    Triangle(int height, int width):Polygon(height, width){}
    void calc_area();
};
```

Comment: um I get now: 37 no matching function for call to `Rectangle::Rectangle(int, int)'

Comment: @user3265784 sorry, i don't compile before, you should add constructors for the each subclass. i update the codes.

Answer (score 0):

To construct `Triangle` and `Rectangle` you are calling their invisible default constructors.

So the `Triangle()` and `Rectangle()` methods. These are implemented as empty methods, but they must also call the default constructors of any class they inherit from. So effectively this is the code that's being generated:

```
Triangle() : Polygon() {}
Rectangle() : Polygon() {}
```

`Polygon` will not get a default constructor because you created your own constructor. So the only way to get that back is to define it:

```
Polygon() {}
```

Or in C++11:

```
Polygon() = default;
```

The default constructor `Triangle()` or `Rectangle()` are called when you instantiate the member variable. So these lines are calling constructors:

```
Rectangle s1;
Triangle s2;
```

Note that once they are constructed they *cannot* be reconstructed. So these calls are illegal:

```
s1.Polygon(5, 2);
s2.Polygon(5, 2);
```

Now if you want to accomplish having a setting constructor, you *can* do that, but you'll need to define it for `Triangle` and `Rectangle`:

```
Triangle(int width, int height) : Polygon(width, height) {}
Triangle(int width, int height) : Polygon(width, height) {}
```

Again recall that defining these methods will cause your default constructor not to be generated for `Triangle` or `Rectangle`. So your `s1` and `s2` declarations will now be illegal, but that's OK cause you want to declare them with your new constructors anyway:

```
Rectangle s1(5, 2);
Triangle s2(5, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use this way...
`Rectangle *s1 = new Rectangle;`
`s1->ab(5,2);`
`s1->calc_area();`